# why long text appears below name?

Tags: html, css, block

[image]

I want the message begin at the right from the name and continue below if its too long

.. like the second text but its short ..

php ;

```
        echo'
            <div class="chatpos">
              <div class="namec">'.$resnamec['username'].'</div>
              <div class="msgc">'.$reschat['message'].'</div>
            </div>';
        }
```

css ;

```
  .chatpos {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 30px;
    float: right;
}

.namec {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: #9aefd8;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.msgc {
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: The issue isn't replicated with the code you provided. please provide exact code where your problem is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `msgc` class is set to `display: inline-block`. Instead, it should be set to `display: inline`. Like so:

```
.msgc {
  display: inline;
}
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxnfzuLv/) to see if this is what you desired.

---

In hindsight, I believe a more reliable approach would be to set both `msgc` and `namec` to `display: block`. Additionally, you may set `namec` to `float: left`, like this:

```
.namec {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: blue;
}

.msgc {
    display: block;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Check [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6jrqbzg/).